# Shift-Space in less

Tags: terminal, less, pager

In modern web browsers and other software with text content, <kbd>Space</kbd> scrolls down more or less a screenful. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> scrolls up in everything but `less`.

How can one use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to scroll up in `less`? Or alternatively, is there another pager (POSIX compatibility is my only requirement) that could do the job?

I was told some terminal emulators, and some terminal UI libraries (ncurses?), don't recognize <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>. Is that a valid issue?

Comment: What's wrong with your *PgUp* button?  Not big enough?

Comment: @goldilocks: There's nothing wrong with *wanting* to use Shift-Space, especially if you're used to using it with other tools. It just happens to be impossible for `less` to distinguish between Space and Shift-Space.

Comment: You could configure your terminal (emulator) to send `b` or `^B` (0x2) upon `<shift-Space>`. Note that `b` is just above the space bar in many keyboard configurations

Comment: @KeithThompson :  Just a friendly jibe I hope.  I do empathize; I'd like `/` universally adopted as "search text" ala various common tools, but at the same time I am wary of imposing excessive meglomaniacal standards which make it *even easier* to do something that can be done with one (universally recognizable) keystroke anyway.  Interesting to learn that in this case it is a technical limitation (see 200_success's answer) and not curmudgeonly design that explains.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: How would you do that for `xterm`?

Comment: @KeithThompson, see the `translations` resource for the VT100 widget.

Answer (score 6):

I think you've brought up a culture clash caused by a technical limitation.  Since <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> generates the same output as <kbd>Space</kbd>, the Unix terminal model treats them identically.  To distinguish between the two, you need a programming environment that supports key up / key down events.  That is possible in X11 and in terminal emulators that support remapping keys.  An example of remapping <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to <kbd>PageUp</kbd>:

```
# For [u]rxvt, in ~/.Xdefaults:
URxvt.keysym.Shift-space: \033[5~
```

Comment: Most terminal emulators support remapping keys, so it's possible to do it with most terminal emulators (`xterm -xrm 'XTerm.VT100.translations: #override Shift <KeyPress> space: string(0x2)'` in xterm for instance, or you send the same sequence as sent upon `<PageUp>`). Of course, that would make entering text while holding the shift key awkward.

Comment: I don't understand where you put this code.
I was wondering if you could help me out please :)

Comment: @Riveascore Create or edit a file in your home directory named `.Xdefaults`, adding that one-line configuration directive.

Answer (score 4):

Terminal emulators send the same character upon <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Shift+Space</kbd>. If they didn't, then it would make it awkward to type text while holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (see [@egmont's answer](/a/320745) that expands on that argument).

However, you could work around that by mapping <kbd>Shift+Space</kbd> to a sequence of characters that would end up inserting a space by default, and for which you could configure applications like `less` to scroll up upon such a keypress.

For instance, such a sequence could be `` ` `` `DEL` `SPC` (change the `DEL` to `BS` on systems where BS is the `erase` character).

For `xterm`, add the resource:

```
XTerm.VT100.translations: #override \
  Shift <KeyPress> space: string("`") string(0x7f) string(" ")
```

And configure `less` with:

```
printf '%s\n' '#command' '`\177\40 back-screen' | lesskey -
```

Answer (score 2):

`less` does not currently support this, but it [definitely could be added](https://github.com/gwsw/less).

If a program uses an [xterm control sequence](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.pdf) to set 
`modifyOtherKeys` to 2 by writing 
`\e[>4;2m` to the terminal, then `xterm` annotates keys with extra information about what modifier keys are active. Specifically for the <kbd>Space</kbd> key, with `modifyOtherKeys` active in xterm, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> turns into `\e[27;2;32~`. `less` would have to properly interpret this as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and then trigger a scroll up.

While this would definitely work in xterm, it wouldn’t work in every terminal application. But those terminals that don’t recognize this escape sequence to turn on `modifyOtherKeys` will just ignore that escape sequence and keep sending programs a normal space character when you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

There is a quite detailed page on the xterm website that explains how `modifyOtherKeys` codes are calculated: https://invisible-island.net/xterm/modified-keys.html

Answer (score 1):

In terminal emulators, this feature would break typing uppercase text with embedded spaces by holding down Shift. E.g. if you wanted to type "It's A Title", you'd have to release Shift between "A" and "T". Keeping it pressed would move away your cursor and misposition the rest of what you type. I believe it would be way more annoying than what you gain with the scroll up feature.

Having the regular behavior when typing text, and scrolling up whenever Space scrolls down would require a redesign and heavy cooperation from apps (e.g. an app being able to toggle what Shift+Space sends), I'm pretty certain it's not going to happen.

The key difference is that a GUI app knows the "context" whether you're editing or viewing content, terminal emulators have no way of knowing this.